# Ants profile shows 150 percent of CPU usage

Tags: red-gate-ants

I am using Red-gate Ants profiler. When I profile my application it shows lot of spikes and show that the CPU usage is 150%.

How is that possible the usage to go beyond 100% ??

Additionally I would really appreciate if anyone can tell me how to troubleshoot and pin point the issues causing this huge usage.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [Red-gate Ants FAQ](http://www.red-gate.com/supportcenter/content/ANTS_Performance_Profiler/articles/app_unexpected_results):

**CPU usage exceeds 100%**

> ANTS Performance Profiler analyzes CPU usage per core. So, on a
>   quad-core machine an application taking all time on all cores would be
>   shown as taking 400% of CPU time.